# How Apple Metal API distinguishes uniforms from vertices buffers?

Tags: shaders, rendering, metal

I am not sure how metal distinguishes uniforms from vertices buffers?
As far as I know code for passing uniforms in buffers are the same like for vertices:

```
[self.commandEncoder setVertexBuffer:positionBuffer offset:0 atIndex:0];
[self.commandEncoder setVertexBuffer:uniformBuffer offset:0 atIndex:1];
```

In shader code there is no keyword defining some struct as uniforms, so how Metal know it? In Opengl GLSL was uniform keyword which was clear for me but I can't figure how it is solved in metal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are defined in vertex shader signature, eg.

```
vertex ColorInOut unlit_vertex(device vertex_t* vertex_array [[ buffer(0) ]],
                            constant uniforms_t& uniforms [[ buffer(1) ]],
                            unsigned int vid [[ vertex_id ]])
```

Earlier I define them like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    matrix_float4x4 _ModelViewProjectionMatrix;
    float4 tintColor;
    matrix_float4x4 _ShadowProjectionMatrix;
} uniforms_t;

typedef struct
{
    packed_float3 position;
    packed_float2 texcoord;
    packed_float3 normal;
    packed_float4 tangent;
    packed_float4 color;
} vertex_t;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer I missed that keyword uniform in shader signature.

Comment: But there is no keyword 'uniform' in the shader signature. uniforms_t is a user defined type - can be anything.